# Javascript text file encoding with Arabic and English for macro file

Tags: javascript, encoding, macros, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I am trying to export a text file using JavaScript to be used as macro for Microsoft Dynamics GP.

The problem is Arabic letters don't render correctly when I try to use the macro in GP.

For example "النسر" would render as "ط§ظ„ظ†ط³ط±"

My JavaScript code uses FileSaver.js

```
var file = new Blob([text], {type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8;"});
saveAs(file, filename);
```

One solution I found was that after downloading the file I save it with ANSI encoding. But if I changed my charset in the JavaScript Blob object to "ansi" or "Windows-1252" or "cp-1252" it doesn't work.

Note: I am using Chrome on Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience I have found that Dynamics GP macros uses ANSI.

You will first need to encode your text to ANSI that includes arabic (windows-1256/CP1256).

I used this js library to encode the text: 
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/windows-1256

```
var text= windows1256.encode(text);
```

Then you will need to convert it to 8 bit unsigned integers and export it using a Blob.

```
var uint8 = new Uint8Array(text.length);
for (var i = 0; i < uint8.length; i++)
{
  uint8[i] = text.charCodeAt(i);
}
var file = new Blob([uint8], {type: 'text/plain;charset=windows-1256'});
```

I know this answer is too late but I hope it helps.

Comment: Well may this answer are late for the asker but at least it helps me now thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old but I am almost positive, unless something has changed recently, that GP database is all non-unicode. This is not going to work for you.